# Latter Delivery Ack. from GCM to App server?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM for Chat App. If User is Offline(not Connected to App but internet is active)  then i Send push notification to devices It receive perfectly. 
But when Device is totally offline(neither connected to App and nor active internet) at that time GCM send me response like { id: XXXXXXXX,success: 3,failure: 2{message_id:xxxxx,ect:..}} on my App server.

two device are totally offline they don't have active internet connection..
when device will connect to internet GCM Send them message.
but how can my App server will Know that Message is delivered by GCM.

I Search a lot but can't get any satisfied answer.
I tried that on messageRecive at client device(Android device) i will send httpRequest to my App server but it not suitable for my app it makes App very slow.

So Question is how Can i know that my failure 2 message are delivered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you do not need to update your app server in case of a downstream message after it is sent to GCM Server. As explained [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm#lifecycle), GCM server stores the message in case of an offline device and delivers it once the device is online.

(Now assuming that what you want is to handle network tasks on the client)
You can use [GcmNetworkManager](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmNetworkManager) to batch network discovery and connectivity related tasks across the system through Play Services. Go through the documentation.

You can use GCM Statistics and Diagnostics from Google Play Developer Console, too. This gives you details of messages handled by a particular app (through Registration token) down to status of specific messages (through message IDs). More explanation [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268#status).

(However I am not too clear exactly what you want)

**EDIT**

> but how can my App server will Know that Message is delivered by GCM.

Sorry, reading through again I realised this is the real question. Answer is pretty straight forward [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs#receipts).

.

Comment: I have tried JAXL and xmpphp but I can't Connect GCM(CCS).

Comment: This is a separate issue and maybe something wrong with the server side code. Put a new post with detailed explanation of the issue and your code for the community. I'm positive you will get the answer or some guidance. :)